# dynamixel_motor support for protocol 2.0

Tags: ros, dynamixel-motor, robotis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone transitioned from protocol 1.0 to 2.0 following recent firmware upgrades? I'm currently using MX-64T's with the dynamixel_motor stack, but I'm trying to understand what upgrading to protocol 2.0 would entail. Is this as simple as updating the control table addresses in dynamixel_const.py? Or would it be best to incorporate the official Robotis DynamixelSDK package in place of the dynamixel_driver package?

Any advice is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268144/dynamixel_motor-support-for-protocol-2.0/) by [ryanoldja](https://answers.ros.org/users/30719/ryanoldja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-08-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend Dynamixel SDK and Dynamixel Workbench package

This Dynamixel SDK package is wrapping version of ROBOTIS Dynamixel SDK for ROS. The ROBOTIS Dynamixel SDK, or SDK, is a software development library that provides Dynamixel control functions for packet communication (both protocol 1.0 and 2.0). And, Dynamixel Workbench package supports to easily change the ID, baud rate and operating mode of the Dynamixel. Furthermore, it supports various controllers based on operating mode and Dynamixel SDK.

- http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_sdk
- http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_workbench

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2017-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0